# mouse hover is not working in safari ,selenium web driver

Tags: java, macos, safari, selenium-webdriver, mousehover

I used the Actions to mouse hover in FF and chrome , it is working fine. But the same code is not working in safari. I am using mac OS and selenium webdriver and java.

I tried below code.

```
 new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```

JS:

```
String mouseOverScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";
                    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                    js.executeScript(mouseOverScript, element);
```

It is a show stopper issue. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if selenium is compatible with the version of Safari you are testing on?

Comment: @YuZhang , yes it is compatible .

Answer (score 4):

Performing mouse hovers requires using WebDriver's Advanced User Interactions API. In the Java language bindings, this is accomplished by the `Actions` class. Unfortunately, at present, the `SafariDriver` [does not implement the Advanced User Interactions API](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4136), so you cannot accomplish this directly. Until it is implemented, you could probably simulate it using JavaScript to fire the events fired my a mouse hover.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the Java script I mentioned above is working fine in one scenario and not in another scenario. it is weird. can you share if you have any java script code snippet? appreciate your help.

Comment: Considering for more than a year now, the Selenium folks have not maintained the Safari Driver, it might not come from them... sigh.

Comment: Mar. '18, still no progress. :(

Comment: @SiKing, considering that the Selenium project no longer maintains a Safari driver, I’m not sure that’s a valid complaint against the project. Apple, however, **does** provide a driver for Safari, and has for some time now. If the actions API isn’t implemented by that driver, it’s hardly the fault of the Selenium project.

Comment: @JimEvans Agreed. I guess my comment should have been more clear: Mar. '18, and still no progress by the current maintainer, Apple.

Comment: Just curious, what would "using JavaScript to fire the events fired my a mouse hover." look like? What goes into the `browser.execute()` for that to work?