# Not able to Mouseover in Selenium Webdriver for Safari

Tags: javascript, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

I want to mouse over an element in selenium webdriver for safari. I have tried following approaches to achieve the mouseover:

1) Using the **Action** class which is advance interaction API but its not supported by the Safari.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(webDriver);
builder.moveToElement(webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("my_locator_xpath"))).build().perform();
```

2) Using following **JavaScript executor** codes:

- ```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;

  js.executeScript("arguments[0].onmouseover()", my_element_locator);
  ```
- ```
  String javaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +"evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +"arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";
  ((JavascriptExecutor)webDriver).executeScript(javaScript, dept_elem);
  ```
- ```
  String mouseOverScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  WebElement someElem = driver.findElement(By.id("some Id")); //replace with your own WebElement call/code here
  js.executeScript(mouseOverScript, someElem);
  ```

3) Using the **Robot** class.

```
Point elem_coords = my_web_element.getLocation();
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(elem_coords.x, elem_coords.y);
```

All above mentioned methods are not able to achieve the mouseover. Code gets executed and I am not even getting any error.

Version configurations I am using are :

- **Mac OS- OS X 10.8**
- **Safari- Version 6.0 (8536.25)**
- **Selenium standalone jar- 2.45**

Comment: Have you looked at [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293914/how-to-perform-mouseover-function-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)?

Comment: @iridann yes i have looked at it. Second javascript mentioned above is from there only!

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655628/mouse-hover-is-not-working-in-safari-selenium-web-driver

Comment: (It's not possible without JavaScript)